# Sub-query result set not read by main query

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have written a query like this :

```
select *
from DATASYNCH_HA_TO_TRG_AUDIT_HIST
where PSX_BATCH_ID IN (select PSX_BATCH_ID
                       from DATASYNCH_HA_TO_TRG_AUDIT_T
                      );
```

Here,when I execute the sub-query alone, it results some values and when I put those values in the place of sub-query the main query also returns some values.But,when I use this whole query ,it does not result any values.How is it possible?

Comment: are you sure column  PSX_BATCH_ID of table DATASYNCH_HA_TO_TRG_AUDIT_HIST has same PSX_BATCH_ID id as DATASYNCH_HA_TO_TRG_AUDIT_T table.

Comment: Needs sample input and output and expected output

Comment: Are these both tables, or is one or both of them a view? What is the [execution plan](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-create-an-execution-plan) for your query?

Comment: And what are the data types of the column in both tables/views?

Comment: Can you share tables' description and sample data

Answer (score 0):

Hope PSX_BATCH_ID column datatype is integer. if it is varchar filed, then trim the value.

SELECT *
FROM DATASYNCH_HA_TO_TRG_AUDIT_HIST
WHERE TRIM(PSX_BATCH_ID) IN
         (SELECT TRIM(PSX_BATCH_ID) FROM DATASYNCH_HA_TO_TRG_AUDIT_T);

Instead of using IN query, use JOIN

SELECT *
FROM DATASYNCH_HA_TO_TRG_AUDIT_HIST    A
     INNER JOIN DATASYNCH_HA_TO_TRG_AUDIT_T B
        ON (A.PSX_BATCH_ID = B.PSX_BATCH_ID)

Answer (score 0):

Really Sorry guys,I found out it was actually a database issue.I ran the query recently in a procedure,it is working fine.